# isKindOfClass for mocked objects with OCMockito returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmockito

I am testing a method, this method call other one that iterates over a `NSArray` of different objects, these objects conform a `protocol <MNBNotificableTrabel>`. This method checks if every object `isKindOfClass: oneClass` or otherClass and return one to me.

```
    for (id <MNBNotificableTravel> travel in self.travelList) {
        if ([travel isGoodForNotification] && [travel notificationType] == MNBNotificableTravelTypeEditable) {
            if ([notificableTravel numberOfPoisOrAssetsForNotification] < [travel numberOfPoisOrAssetsForNotification]) {
                if ([travel isKindOfClass:[MNBNotificableTravelList class]] && !notificableTravel])) {
                    notificableTravel = travel;
                } else if ([travel isKindOfClass:[MNBNotificablePoiListDraft class]]) {
                    notificableTravel = travel;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return notificableTravel;
}
```

To test it I have created a fake array with `mockedObjects`. I have created them in different methods and not using `mockProtocol()`, because I want to distinguish between them.

```
- (MNBNotificableTravelList *)fakeTravelListGoodForNotification:(BOOL)good numberOfPois:(NSUInteger)numberOfPois type:(MNBNotificableTravelType)type travelId:(NSString *)travelId {
    MNBNotificableTravelList * fakeTravel = mock([MNBNotificableTravelList class]);
    [given([fakeTravel isGoodForNotification]) willReturnBool:good];
    [given([fakeTravel notificationType]) willReturnInteger:type];
    [given([fakeTravel numberOfPoisOrAssetsForNotification]) willReturnInteger:numberOfPois];
    [given([fakeTravel travelID]) willReturn:travelId];
    return fakeTravel;
}

- (MNBNotificablePoiListDraft *)fakePoiListDraftGoodForNotification:(BOOL)good numberOfPois:(NSUInteger)numberOfPois type:(MNBNotificableTravelType)type travelId:(NSString *)travelId {
    MNBNotificablePoiListDraft * fakeTravel = mock([MNBNotificablePoiListDraft class]);
    [given([fakeTravel isGoodForNotification]) willReturnBool:good];
    [given([fakeTravel notificationType]) willReturnInteger:type];
    [given([fakeTravel numberOfPoisOrAssetsForNotification]) willReturnInteger:numberOfPois];
    [given([fakeTravel travelID]) willReturn:travelId];
    return fakeTravel;
}

- (void)testBuildLocalNotificationShouldCallScheduleMethodFourTimes {
    NSDate *installationDate = [NSDate date];
    [given([self.mockUserDefaults boolForKey:mnbUserHasAuthorizedLocation]) willReturnBool:YES];
    [given([self.mockUserDefaults objectForKey:mnbInstallationDateKey]) willReturn:installationDate];
    [given([self.mockDateGenerator notificationDatesForScheduleLifeCycleNotifications]) willReturn:[self fakeNotificationDatesWithInstallationDate:installationDate]];
    NSArray *fakeTravels = @[[self fakePoiListDraftGoodForNotification:YES numberOfPois:3 type:MNBNotificableTravelTypePublished travelId:@"1"],
                             [self fakePoiListDraftGoodForNotification:YES numberOfPois:3 type:MNBNotificableTravelTypeEditable travelId:@"3" ]];

    MNBLifeCycleNotificationBuilder *customSut = [[MNBLifeCycleNotificationBuilder alloc] initWithUserDefaults:self.mockUserDefaults application:self.mockApplication travelList:fakeTravels];
    [customSut buildLocalNotifications];
    [verifyCount(self.mockApplication, times(4)) scheduleLocalNotification:instanceOf([UILocalNotification class])];
}
```

My problem comes when I iterate over this `NSArray`, if I type `po travel` the output is right and I see that it is a mock of `MNBNotificableTravelList` or `MNBNotificablePoiListDraft`, but if I type `po [travel isKindOfClass:[MNBNotificableTravelList class]]` the output is always `nil`.

I have tried to add the response to `[isKindOfClass:]` using `given`. But I think this is not a good way, and the response is an hex number.

Anyone knows how could I test this correctly.

Thank you

Comment: Odd. OCMockito has supported `isKindOfClass:` from early on.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It is weird, but I get nil.. I am going to do @KirkSpaziani's Solution 1 and avoid to use introspection.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Don't use isKindOfClass in your code.  Introspection is cool, but it's almost always a better practice to avoid using it. A method on the protocol that all the entries conform to can be used to consolidate logic, or using a pattern like Inversion Of Control: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control can help you avoid asking objects what type they are and switching based on it.

Solution 2: Mocking/Overriding isKindOfClass: should be fine.  These are mock objects, they're supposed to behave in nonstandard ways. Take a look at the NSObject documentation for [isKindOfClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:): and isMemberOfClass: and override them in your mock objects.